# How to get available flags out of an ArgumentParser object?

Tags: python, command-line-arguments, argparse

I'm using the `argparse` module for this python project. I'm looking to get the available flags out of an `ArgumentParser` object before calling `parse_args()`. Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Got this from the source code of add_argument():

```
>>> import argparse
>>> parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
>>> parser.add_argument('-v', '--verbosity', help='more debug info', action='store_true')
_StoreTrueAction(option_strings=['-v', '--verbosity'], dest='verbosity', nargs=0, const=True, default=False, type=None, choices=None, help='more debug info', metavar=None)
>>> parser._option_string_actions.keys()
['-v', '-h', '--verbosity', '--help']
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

I was trying to solve this the other day and I never got a satisfactory answer other than the following on from  what @vvoody did.

```
In [117]: map(lambda x : x.dest,parser._actions)
Out[117]: ['help', 'verbosity']
```

The benefit is that it removes all the alias `-v` == `--verbosity` etc.  **BUT** if you change `dest` for `--verbosity`  e.g `dest='loud'`  then it returns `loud` which may or may not be an issue.

Seems an obvious thing for `argsparse` to provide out of the box.

Comment: I think vvoody's is closer to what I need. It is sort of weird that we have to access a private method for either of these things though :/

Comment: In my case I was trying to set options to default to env vars so that ``$FOO=bar`` in the environment would set the dest=foo, whether it was ``--foo`` or ``-f`` or whatever.  Agreed that is seems weird to use private methods to access the data esp. when there can be a mismatch between option and the intenal model help by argparse.