# How does argparse store all of the added argument? Is there a way to access their names, and help strings?

Tags: python

I'm trying to generate some external documentation for a large program which has a ton of optional arguments (which get expanded/changed frequently). I'm curious if there is a way to access the arguments from the `parser` object so that I can see all of the names, descriptions, helps, etc.. for everything that was passed to it. The `parse_args()` function removes all of the additional info and just returns the key/value pairs.

For example, if I have the following code:

```
import argparse

def main():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Description of your program')
    parser.add_argument('-f','--foo', help='Foo help string')
    parser.add_argument('-b','--bar', help='Bar help string')
    parser.add_argument('-z','--zar', help='Zar help string')
    args = parser.parse_args()
```

Is there some way to get a list of all the arguments in parser? Something along the lines of

```
[{'dest':'--f', 'help':'Foo help string'}, {'dest':'-b', 'help':etc...)]
```

If I could get something like that, it'd make marking up some pretty html documentation a breeze.

Comment: For making doco, why not use the usage formatter instead?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get available flags out of an ArgumentParser object?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14913855/how-to-get-available-flags-out-of-an-argumentparser-object)

Comment: `parser.format_help()` produces the help in a multiline string that you can play with.  Otherwise, use the `parser._actions` to extract the data yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Internally, the `ArgumentParser` stores these in the `_actions` attribute:

```
In [21]: parser._actions
Out[21]: 
[_HelpAction(option_strings=['-h', '--help'], dest='help', nargs=0, const=None, default='==SUPPRESS==', type=None, choices=None, help='show this help message and exit', metavar=None),
 _StoreAction(option_strings=['-f', '--foo'], dest='foo', nargs=None, const=None, default=None, type=None, choices=None, help='Foo help string', metavar=None),
 _StoreAction(option_strings=['-b', '--bar'], dest='bar', nargs=None, const=None, default=None, type=None, choices=None, help='Bar help string', metavar=None),
 _StoreAction(option_strings=['-z', '--zar'], dest='zar', nargs=None, const=None, default=None, type=None, choices=None, help='Zar help string', metavar=None)]
```

You can also find them with their command-line options as keys in the `_option_string_actions` attribute:

```
In [14]: parser._option_string_actions
Out[14]: 
{'--bar': _StoreAction(option_strings=['-b', '--bar'], dest='bar', nargs=None, const=None, default=None, type=None, choices=None, help='Bar help string', metavar=None),
 '--foo': _StoreAction(option_strings=['-f', '--foo'], dest='foo', nargs=None, const=None, default=None, type=None, choices=None, help='Foo help string', metavar=None),
 '--help': _HelpAction(option_strings=['-h', '--help'], dest='help', nargs=0, const=None, default='==SUPPRESS==', type=None, choices=None, help='show this help message and exit', metavar=None),
 '--zar': _StoreAction(option_strings=['-z', '--zar'], dest='zar', nargs=None, const=None, default=None, type=None, choices=None, help='Zar help string', metavar=None),
 '-b': _StoreAction(option_strings=['-b', '--bar'], dest='bar', nargs=None, const=None, default=None, type=None, choices=None, help='Bar help string', metavar=None),
 '-f': _StoreAction(option_strings=['-f', '--foo'], dest='foo', nargs=None, const=None, default=None, type=None, choices=None, help='Foo help string', metavar=None),
 '-h': _HelpAction(option_strings=['-h', '--help'], dest='help', nargs=0, const=None, default='==SUPPRESS==', type=None, choices=None, help='show this help message and exit', metavar=None),
 '-z': _StoreAction(option_strings=['-z', '--zar'], dest='zar', nargs=None, const=None, default=None, type=None, choices=None, help='Zar help string', metavar=None)}
```